# Eclipse: Problems with JNI code debugging

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, java-native-interface

### Background

I'm writing application for android, using Eclipse in Windows. I'm implementing ***C*** code in ***JAVA*** and for that I'm using ***JNI***. I have many functions and my problem is that I want to ***debug functions in JNI***.

### Question

***Can I debug my code which is written in JNI in C language ?***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is answer [***How to start logging for Android NDK***](http://vitobrothersoft.com/2011/06/17/how-to-start-logging-for-android-ndk/) !

Some weeks I was researching how I can write logs in Eclipse from Android NDK code. I found some examples in Internet and want to share it with you. Following  steps below you can start logging on Eclipse.

1. Include log.h file into your Android NDK source file

   ```
   #include <android/log.h>
   ```
2. Add the line below to your  Android.mk make file.

   ```
   LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
   ```

Now you can start logging, this two steps allows you to write logs in Eclipse from Android NDK. Write the line below in your Android NDK code and the log will bw appear in the Eclipse

```
__android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR,"Tag","Message");
```

use following Flags to write logs in the column which you want.

```
typedef enum android_LogPriority {
    ANDROID_LOG_UNKNOWN = 0,
    ANDROID_LOG_DEFAULT,    /* only for SetMinPriority() */
    ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE,
    ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG,
    ANDROID_LOG_INFO,
    ANDROID_LOG_WARN,
    ANDROID_LOG_ERROR,
    ANDROID_LOG_FATAL,
    ANDROID_LOG_SILENT,     /* only for SetMinPriority(); must be last */
} android_LogPriority
```

For example if you want to write in Info column you must write

```
__android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_INFO,"Tag","Message");
```

So, Good Luck !

Comment: +1 its a nice answer... I also have some strange problem can you help me out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11324340/surprise-behavior-of-eclipse-for-c-files-while-using-jni-why-so