# Surprise behavior of eclipse for C files while using JNI, Why so?

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu, java-native-interface

I am developing an Android App in which I use lot of JNI Code.. Recently (from last 2-3 days I am really annoyed by surprise behavior of eclipse) it shows me vague errors as soon as I open my .c file... However errors disappear if I close and reopen the project. See the secreen shot attached. Is it because I just update my eclipse installation (just update of eclipse plugins, I am still on my old Indigo)...

[image]

Is it an eclibse bug or something wrong with my setup ?

**Solved ????**
I tried everything but noting could change the behavior of eclipse.. By this time I knew that I have certainly messed with the project Settings by mistake, since eclipse was behaving well in other projects of same workspace. So I recreated the project manually and finally that solved myproblem...Though the Question is still open for valuable answers I think soon I will get some good answers..

**UPDATE**
Even eclipse 4.2 release also has this problem.. #frustrating

Comment: is the eclipse c/c++ indexer faults. I am stucked with it too.

Comment: @blackbelt please see the answer and this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11504258/how-to-remove-native-support-from-an-android-project-in-eclipse-because-eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that deleting the project and than reimporting the project to workspace solves the problem. However I also came to knew that deleting **.cproject** file from the project tree can also fix this problem. Fixing the NDK path **(Window -> Preferences -> Android-> NDK)** in Eclipse preferences may also solve the problem.

**Solution 2** Which may work in few cases...

1. Right click on the project.
2. Select Android Tools -> Fix Project Properties

Comment: for more information see my another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11504258/how-to-remove-native-support-from-an-android-project-in-eclipse-because-eclipse