# How to remove native support from an Android Project in eclipse because eclipse is showing errors in jni?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I accidentally clicked on "Add Native Support" inside "Android Tools"... That messed up all the  jni files of my project. How do I undo that ? How to remove Native support from my Android Project ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

With the new ADT 20, if the project has a jni folder or/and an Android.mk file the c++ nature is added by the plugin by default,

In general to remove the C++ nature, you just need to delete the .cproject file in the project tree, remove and re-import project in the workspace and you're good to go (c++ project nature removed).

But I think you should just add the macro definitions and build imports and eclipse will work just fine. 
If you go to

```
Project properties->C/C++ general->Paths and symbols
```

and there you add the path to the NDK includes for the corresponding platform
(something like)

```
{NDK_PATH}/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/include
```

and all your build script added imports as well as any build script declared macros
eclipse will handle the jni stuff just fine.

Answer (score 33):

The only way I could find to reliably removed the C nature from the project was by hand editing Eclipse's `.project` file for the project.

1. Close the Eclipse project (e.g. by quitting Eclipse).
2. Open the `.project` file in a text or xml editor. There will be at least 2 `<buildCommand>` nodes that need to be removed. Remove the `<buildCommand>` node with name `org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.genmakebuilder` and all its children, and the `<buildCommand>` node with name `org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.ScannerConfigBuilder` and its children. Finally, remove the lines:

   `<nature>org.eclipse.cdt.core.cnature</nature>`
   `<nature>org.eclipse.cdt.core.ccnature</nature>`
   `<nature>org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.managedBuildNature</nature>`
   `<nature>org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.ScannerConfigNature</nature>`
3. Completely remove the `.cproject` file.

Comment: it is sometimes necessary (as of eclipse Kepler at least) to delete the project reference from your workspace (not contents on disk) and then re-import it after following the above steps.  See http://pilcrowpipe.blogspot.com/2011/12/removing-native-support-from-android.html

Comment: It worked for me, Thank you. I've removed the build comands from eclipse, and now I don't see C/C++ in the properties of my project.

Comment: It worked for me too. But I needed to delete project from eclipse and re-import it again.

Comment: also delete .externalToolBuilders from your project root folder if exist

Comment: The steps above were helpful but after following them I could no longer build my app. I was getting a fairly obtuse error message: make: *** [clean-installed-binaries] Error 127. Searching for this error message did not provide any indication of the specific problem or a solution. The only solution I found was to remove the project and then re-add it and then the problem magically went away.

Comment: Done steps suggested by bleater and then @CCJ, solve my issue.

Answer (score 4):

Open up your `.project` file in a text editor and just delete the entries for CDT and C nature. They are easily distinguished from those of JDT. I have done this several times and it's nothing dangerous but make a backup copy for safety.

EDIT: It might be possible also with Project Properties -> Builders -> Remove CDT Builder but never tried it.

Comment: I had to delete the project and then import it into the workspace before Eclipse was happy.

Answer (score 2):

Do following steps, Hope it can help you.

After Android tools ->Add native support.
It will gen cpp file on jni folder. And eclipse can not resolved it.
This is a fixing way.

1. Step 1

   Right Click PJ -> add New Folder -> In dialog add new folder, click Advanced>> check Linked Folder -> Borrow to [{NDK_PATH}/platforms/android-21/arch-arm/usr/include ] ( i used android -21, you can change it) (1)--> OK
2. Step 2

   Right click PJ -> Properties -> C/CC general ->Paths and Symbols ->Include tab -> Add ->Work Space -> select include folder (1) in your project -> OK . Refresh and rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

just remove the jni folder and clear project in c/c++ interface