# C JNI code introduces errors in an Android Eclipse project once the C file is opened in the editor

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have an Android project setup in Eclipse which uses the JNI to access C code, and everything does work fine until I open one of the C files. Once that's done I get these errors:

---

[image]

---

I have tried quite a bit of things, including this:

[Surprise behavior of eclipse for C files while using JNI, Why so?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11324340/surprise-behavior-of-eclipse-for-c-files-while-using-jni-why-so)

My NDK path is also set like so:

[image]

Has anyone got a solution to this? Please note that closing the project and reopening makes the problem go away but once you open a C source file the problem appears again. Also note, that the project compiles, runs and makes use of the JNI wrapper and underlying C source just fine if I do not open a C file.

EDIT:

When hovering towards the explicit red bugs I get messages like **Type jstring could not be resolved**. I kind of understand what the problem might be, what I don't understand is that why is this a problem only when I open the source file? And why, If i don't open the file in the editor, this works perfectly?

EDIT 2:

I forgot to mention that I am doing this on a mac.

Comment: Known bug, check this thread for some solutions: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=33788

Comment: Note that this is an *indexing* issue, you will be able to compile just fine.

Answer (score 3):

[Eclipse compiles successfully but still gives semantic errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16786555/eclipse-compiles-successfully-but-still-gives-semantic-errors)
In your selected project preferences within the Eclipse environment, go to C/C++ General -> Code Analysis -> Launching. Make sure that both check boxes are unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's old question. But update you CDT and everything will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Also for anyone that might have this error, make sure that in `C/C++ General -> Code Analysis`, the option `Syntax and Semantic Errors` is unchecked:

[image]